# javascript freemarker springmvc spring.ftl

Tags: javascript, validation, spring-mvc, freemarker

how to use javascript invoke spring freemarker macro?

```
<@spring.formInput "message.title" 'id="message1" size="10" name="message1"'/> 
<@spring.showErrors "<br>", "error"/>`

alert(document.getElementsById("message1"));
```

can not done?

why?

Answer (score 0):

because this not how freemarker works, when using `<@spring.formInput/>` what actually occures is that:

```
<#macro formInput path attributes="" fieldType="text">
    <@bind path/>
    <input type="${fieldType}" id="${status.expression}" name="${status.expression}" value="<#if fieldType!="password">${stringStatusValue}</#if>" ${attributes}<@closeTag/>
</#macro>
```

so the id is going to be (in your case) 'title' and some times it doesn't occurr my advice is to add class attribute and get your element by class to avoid having any conflict with freemarker

so you should go like this:

```
<@spring.formInput "message.title" 'class="myClass" size="10"'/> 
<@spring.showErrors "<br>", "error"/>`

alert(document.getElementsByClass("myClass"));
```

this will definitely work. I hope this would help